# Tensor product over ring of smooth functions vs. tensor product over reals

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, modules, tensor-products

Suppose we have two smooth vector bundles $E_1 \to M$ and $E_2 \to M$. Is it true in general that $\Gamma(E_1) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \Gamma(E_2) = \Gamma(E_1) \otimes_{C^\infty (M)} \Gamma(E_2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you want.

There is an obvious map

$$\Gamma(E_1) \otimes_\mathbb{R} \Gamma(E_2) \to \Gamma(E_1) \otimes_{C^\infty(M)} \Gamma(E_2)$$

which sends $s_1 \otimes _{\mathbb R} s_2$ to $s_1 \otimes_\infty s_2$ (write $\otimes_\infty  = \otimes_{C^\infty(M)}$ for simplicity). This map is never an isomorphism (as $\mathbb R$-module), unless $M$ is a point.

To see this let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be two disjoint nonempty open sets in $M$ and $s_1, s_2$ are nonzero sections of $E_1, E_2$ supported on $V_1, V_2$ respectively. Then $s_1 \otimes_{\mathbb R} s_2 \neq 0$ while $s_1 \otimes_\infty s_2= 0$.